# How to refactor this code so I can make changes more easily

Tags: c#, design-patterns, refactoring

I have around 40 datasets forms on my project split in 8 dataset groups.I ll try to explain as simple as possible. Let take `IDCards` group for example. There I have 2 datasets, `ValidIDCards`and `ValidIDCardsForeigners`.
Currently, for every dataset, my backend folder structure looks like (I ll use `ValidIDCards` as example):

```
ValidIdCards
    -Commands
        -Create
              - CreateValidIDCardsCommandModel
              - CreateValidIDCardsCommandHandler
              - CreateValidIDCardsCommandValidator
        -Update
              - CreateValidIDCardsCommandModel
              - CreateValidIDCardsCommandHandler
              - CreateValidIDCardsCommandValidator

        -Other commands..

    -Queries
            -GetAll
                  - GetAllValidIDCardsQueryModel
                  - GetAllValidIDCardsQueryHandler
                  - GetAllValidIDCardsQueryViewModel
            -GetbyId
                  - GetByIdValidIDCardsQueryModel
                  - GetByIdValidIDCardsQueryHandler
                  - GetByValidIDCardsQueryViewModel

           -Other queries..
```

Now, take a look at `Create` command.
`CreateValidIDCardsCommandModel` looks like:

```
 public class CreateValidIDCardsCommandModel : IRequest<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Institution { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int CountryID{ get; set;} //foreign key to another table
}
```

`CreateValidIDCardsCommandHandler` looks like:

```
 public async Task<int> Handle(CreateValidIDCardsCommandModel request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {       
      var country = _context.Countries.Where(x => 
      x.Code == request.CountryID)).FirstOrDefault();

        var newItem = new Domain.Entities.ValidIdcard
        {
            Institution = request.Institution,
            Total = request.Total,
            CountryID = country.number,
        };
        _context.ValidIdcards.Add(newItem);     
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

and in `CreateValidIDCardsCommandValidator` I validate those fields.

Now take a look at `Create` command in `ValidIDCardsForeigners`.
`Model` is:

```
     public class CreateValidIDCardsForeignerCommandModel : IRequest<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public string Citizenship {get; set;}
    public int CountryID{ get; set;} //foreign key to another table
}
```

`Handler` looks like:

```
 public async Task<int> Handle(CreateValidIDCardsForeignersCommandModel request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
      var country = _context.Countries.Where(x => 
      x.Code == request.CountryID)).FirstOrDefault();

    var newItem = new Domain.Entities.ValidIdcardForeigner
    {
        Total = request.Total,
        CountryID = country.number,
        Citizenship = request.Citizenship;
    };
    _context.ValidIdcards.Add(newItem);     
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

As you can see,  difference between `ValidIDCards` and `ValidIDCardsForeigners` is in two fields in `Model` and different `new Domain.Entities.Entity` in `Handler` Now, problem is if I for example want to change field `CountryID`  to `string`(and this is real life situation that happened to me)
. I need to edit 40 datasets, several commands and queries for every dataset, (and that is over 100 files for single common change). Also, if I want to add new dataset, it takes me almost a day to copy and change almost 80% of same code.

I thought about making one global `CreateCommandModel` where I would put all fields that most of datasets have `(id, countryID, institution)`, and then inherit in every dataset, but that would not work because not all of datasets have these fields, and few datasets have totaly different fields. I was looking for help in some design patterns, but could not find one to help me.

So, question is how to refactor this code, so when I need to change one thing I don't need to change on 40+ places.

Comment: If you've got working code that you're trying to improve, https://codereview.stackexchange.com is the place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the [design principle says](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337413/what-does-it-mean-when-one-says-encapsulate-what-varies):

> Encapsulate what varies

So let's try to apply this principle.

Assuming `CreateValidIDCardsCommandModel` and `CreateValidIDCardsForeignerCommandModel` has the same interface IRequest:

```
public interface IRequest<T>
{
    public T Id { get; set; }

    public T CountryId { get; set; }
}

public class CreateValidIDCardsCommandModel : IRequest<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Institution { get; set; }

    public int Total { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
}

public class CreateValidIDCardsForeignerCommandModel : IRequest<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Total { get; set; }

    public string Citizenship { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

And it can be concluded that `ValidIdcardForeigner` and `ValidIdcard` share the same interface as it is used in the following code snippet

```
_context.ValidIdcards.Add(newItem);
```

So we can reduce coupling in `Handle()` method by adding parameter `U item`. So we delegated creation of object to client of `Handle` method:

```
public async Task<T> Handle<T, U>(IRequest<T> request, U item, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var country = _context.Countries.Where(x =>
    x.Code == request.CountryID)).FirstOrDefault();

    _context.ValidIdcards.Add(Item);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

By doing this we do not need to edit `Handle` method by adding new `ValidIdcardForeigner` or `ValidIdcard`.